# Ts-jest not running properly

Tags: javascript, node.js, unit-testing, jestjs, ts-jest

I am trying to use ts-jest to write tests using jest with typescript. However, I am facing the following error when I run npm test. I have just one test file `util.test.ts` in tests folder

```
Test suite failed to run

Unable to process 'C:\Users\sayan\Desktop\Dev\packages\fake-json-server\tests\util.test.ts', please make sure that `outDir` in your tsconfig is neither `''` or `'.'`. You can also configure Jest config option `transformIgnorePatterns` to inform `ts-jest` to transform C:\Users\sayan\Desktop\Dev\packages\fake-json-server\tests\util.test.ts
```

package.json

```
{
...
"scripts": {
    "tsc:watch": "tsc -w",
    "test": "jest"
  },
"devDependencies": {
    "@types/express": "^4.17.14",
    "@types/figlet": "^1.5.5",
    "@types/jest": "^29.1.2",
    "@types/node": "^18.8.3",
    "@types/yargs": "^17.0.13",
    "concurrently": "^7.4.0",
    "jest": "^29.1.2",
    "nodemon": "^2.0.20",
    "ts-jest": "^29.0.3",
    "ts-node": "^10.9.1",
    "typescript": "^4.8.4"
  }
}
```

tsconfig.json

```
{
  "include": ["src"],
  "exclude": ["node_modules", "tests"],
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "ES5",
    "module": "CommonJS",
    "rootDir": "src",
    "outDir": "dist",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "checkJs": true,
    "removeComments": true,
    "noEmitOnError": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "strict": true,
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "skipDefaultLibCheck": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true
  }
}
```

jest.config.js. This config is generated using `npx ts-jest config:init`

```
/** @type {import('ts-jest').JestConfigWithTsJest} */
module.exports = {
  preset: 'ts-jest',
  testEnvironment: 'node',
};
```

util.test.ts

```
import { Util } from "../src/util/Util";

describe("object has key", () => {
  test("simple key", () => {
    expect(Util.hasKey("foo", { foo: "bar" })).toBe(true);
    expect(Util.hasKey("foo", {})).toBe(false);
    expect(Util.hasKey("foo", { bar: "foo" })).toBe(false);
  });
});
```

Comment: Can you add the contents of your test file?

Comment: @AaronMeese Hi. I have added the test file

Comment: looks like the error is saying that it can't find your outDir. Do you have the dist directory available before you run the tests?

Comment: @Shaunak. Yes I have the tsc running in watch mode in a terminal already.

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the include/exclude properties from your `tsconfig.json` then create several tsconfig files:

tsconfig.json

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "ES5",
    "module": "CommonJS",
    "rootDir": "src",
    "outDir": "dist",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "checkJs": true,
    "removeComments": true,
    "noEmitOnError": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "strict": true,
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "skipDefaultLibCheck": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true
  }
}
```

tsconfig.build.json

```
{
  "extends": "./tsconfig.json",
  "include": [
    "src"
  ],
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "tests"
  ]
}
```

tsconfig.test.json

```
{
  "extends": "./tsconfig.json",
  "include": [
    "tests"
  ],
  "exclude": []
}
```

Modify jest config to use `tsconfig.test.json`

jest.config.js

```
/** @type {import("ts-jest").JestConfigWithTsJest} */
module.exports = {
  preset: "ts-jest",
  testEnvironment: "node",
  transform: {
    "^.+\\.tsx?$": ["ts-jest", { tsconfig: "tsconfig.test.json" }]
  }
};
```